# bash script to test user input using read command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do something really simple:  Give myself the ability to choose what to run on boot.  This is on a Raspberry Pi so sometimes it will be headless, sometimes it won't.  I thought a simple approach would just be to run a little script on boot (don't even know if this will work - haven't gotten that far yet) that either lets me mash the keyboard and start up the GUI or just time out and start a python script.  But yeah, I'm failing at this simple task.  The if statement always evaluates to true no matter what I try, and I've tried many, many things.  Here is the iteration I *want* to use...

If I let it time out, the return value of the read command should be greater than 128. If I press something the return value should be zero.  So...

```
#!/bin/bash

# this gives the user the chance to startx or leave it alone and let camera.py run
# we will give the user 5 seconds to make a choice

/bin/echo "Hit any key to startx, otherwise I will start camera.py."

if [[ "$(read -t 5 -n 1)" -eq 0 ]]; then
    /bin/echo "You want to startx!"
else
    /bin/echo "You want to start the python script!"
fi
```

The result I get is that it always evaluates to true.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if [[ "$(read -t 5 -n 1)" -eq 0 ]]; then
```

With:

```
if read -t 5 -n 1; then
```

If you type a character, `read` returns and exit code of zero (true).  If `read` reaches end-of-file or it times out, it returns an exit code greater than zero (false).  `if` responds to exit codes.  There is no need for any test (`[[`) commands.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you!  I have to wait 8 minutes before I can hit the check mark, though.